# Magento 1.9 REST API Invalid auth/bad request (got a 500, expected HTTP/1.1 20X or a redirect)

Tags: rest, magento

I am getting this error while i request REST API in Magento 1.9.3

```
   OAuthException Object
(
    [message:protected] => Invalid auth/bad request (got a 500, expected HTTP/1.1 20X or a redirect)
    [string:Exception:private] => 
    [code:protected] => 500

)
```

Comment: Please amend with your code. So, I can give you more specific help

Comment: Did you solve the issue?

Answer (score 0):

**Preparing for REST API**

These steps are required for utilizing REST API resources:

1. Set up permissions for REST resource operations from Magento Admin
   Panel.
2. Configure the attributes for different users types in Magento Admin
   Panel.
3. There are 3 different types of users in accessing the data: Admin,
   Customer, and Guest. Admin is the backend logged in user, Customer
   is the fronted logged in user, and Guest is a non-logged in fronted
   user.

**Preparing REST API for the Third-Party Application**

1. Register the third-party application (Consumer) in Magento Admin
   Panel.
2. The third-party application will utilize the provided consumer
   credentials to call Magento store for getting the access token to
   access the data.

**PHP Example**

**Create a simple product as an Admin user with OAuth authentication**

```
    <?php
/**
* Example of simple product POST using Admin account via Magento REST API. OAuth authorization is used
*/
$callbackUrl = "http://yourhost/oauth_admin.php";
$temporaryCredentialsRequestUrl = "http://magentohost/oauth/initiate?oauth_callback=" . urlencode($callbackUrl);
$adminAuthorizationUrl = 'http://magentohost/admin/oauth_authorize';
$accessTokenRequestUrl = 'http://magentohost/oauth/token';
$apiUrl = 'http://magentohost/api/rest';
$consumerKey = 'yourconsumerkey';
$consumerSecret = 'yourconsumersecret';

session_start();
if (!isset($_GET['oauth_token']) && isset($_SESSION['state']) && $_SESSION['state'] == 1) {
    $_SESSION['state'] = 0;
}
try {
    $authType = ($_SESSION['state'] == 2) ? OAUTH_AUTH_TYPE_AUTHORIZATION : OAUTH_AUTH_TYPE_URI;
    $oauthClient = new OAuth($consumerKey, $consumerSecret, OAUTH_SIG_METHOD_HMACSHA1, $authType);
    $oauthClient->enableDebug();

    if (!isset($_GET['oauth_token']) && !$_SESSION['state']) {
        $requestToken = $oauthClient->getRequestToken($temporaryCredentialsRequestUrl);
        $_SESSION['secret'] = $requestToken['oauth_token_secret'];
        $_SESSION['state'] = 1;
        header('Location: ' . $adminAuthorizationUrl . '?oauth_token=' . $requestToken['oauth_token']);
        exit;
    } else if ($_SESSION['state'] == 1) {
        $oauthClient->setToken($_GET['oauth_token'], $_SESSION['secret']);
        $accessToken = $oauthClient->getAccessToken($accessTokenRequestUrl);
        $_SESSION['state'] = 2;
        $_SESSION['token'] = $accessToken['oauth_token'];
        $_SESSION['secret'] = $accessToken['oauth_token_secret'];
        header('Location: ' . $callbackUrl);
        exit;
    } else {
        $oauthClient->setToken($_SESSION['token'], $_SESSION['secret']);
        $resourceUrl = "$apiUrl/products";
        $productData = json_encode(array(
            'type_id'           => 'simple',
            'attribute_set_id'  => 4,
            'sku'               => 'simple' . uniqid(),
            'weight'            => 1,
            'status'            => 1,
            'visibility'        => 4,
            'name'              => 'Simple Product',
            'description'       => 'Simple Description',
            'short_description' => 'Simple Short Description',
            'price'             => 99.95,
            'tax_class_id'      => 0,
        ));
        $headers = array('Content-Type' => 'application/json');
        $oauthClient->fetch($resourceUrl, $productData, OAUTH_HTTP_METHOD_POST, $headers);
        print_r($oauthClient->getLastResponseInfo());
    }
} catch (OAuthException $e) {
    print_r($e);
}
```

Comment: $oauthClient->fetch($resourceUrl, array(), 'POST', array('Content-Type' => 'application/json', 'Accept' => 'application/json'));

Comment: Try  
$oauthClient->fetch($resourceUrl, array(), 'GET', array('Content-Type' => 'application/json', 'Accept' => */*));

Comment: Not working dear....  debugInfo  is like below : http://prntscr.com/evxuyu

Comment: It was issue with Php version. It's not working in php 5.6

Comment: Not sure then double check your pecl/oauth package that's installed

Comment: Any luck with this? Having the same issue... trying to use Oauth 1.0 in PHP 7.2 with pretty much the exact same code for M1. Getting same error.